# Uniform (but not normal) convergence of a series of function

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

consider the series of function $\sum f_n$ with $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+n^2}$. 
It is easy to see that there is pointwise convergence on $\mathbb{R}$ (to a function that we'll call $f$) but not normal convergence. I want to know whether there is uniform convergence towards $f$ or not.

I tried to disprove uniform convergence by looking at $|\sum_{k=0}^n f_k(n)-f(n)|$ : the sum is unbounded and equivalent to $\ln n$. The problem is that I don't know how to estimate $f(n)$.

I'm sure I'm missing something not too difficult here, so help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider only positive $x$, then all $f_k(x)$ are positive, and we have

$$\left\lvert\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x) - f(x) \right\rvert = f(x) - \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x) = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty f_k(x).$$

Now let's choose a suitable $x$, say $x = 2n$. Then

$$f(2n) - \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(2n) > \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} f_k(2n) > n\cdot f_{2n}(2n) = \frac14,$$

so the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: thanks ! I wasn't too far off but I had trouble writing it down

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** find where $f_n'(x)=0$, look at $x=n$, $f_n(x)$ has maximum, and $M_n={1\over 2n}$ as $\sum {1\over 2n}$ is divergent so your series is not uniformly convergent.

Comment: hmm, that would prove that there is no normal convergence, but there could still be uniform convergence unless I'm missing something ?

Comment: you are talking about normal convergence : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence
I want to know about uniform convergence (see section "distinction")

Comment: you better read this result carefully: $f_n$ be a sequ of function such that $|f_n\le M_n \forall n$ then $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly if $\sum M_n$ converges

Comment: @Sade But that's a sufficient condition, not a necessary one.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you !

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you